# How to read markdown code from a file from an R markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

I'm writing an application in R markdown with Shiny. In one page "Explore", I would show some interactive plots and in another "About" I would write some description of the app and its usage.

I want this section also to be the README file in the GitLab repository where it will be submitted, so it needs to be in markdown. I'm wondering if there is a way to call that README file from the R markdown document, so I do not need to maintain the same text in two files.

Let's consider the following example.

**R markdown file**

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
vertical_layout: fill
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
```


Explore
======================================================================

### PLOT 1
```{r}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) + geom_point()
```

### PLOT 2
```{r}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=qsec)) + geom_point()
```

About
============================================================================

#### README

A brief description of the document.
````

I'm asking specifically if the two text lines under "About" could be substituted by some function that reads a markdown file. So that the following file could be used as README and as about section in the app.

**Markdown file**

```
#### README

A brief description of the document.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion using `readLines`.

Define a function to read the .md-file using `readLines()`, then replace empty lines with newlines, `\n`, finally concatenate and print using `cat`

```
pasteReadme <- function(fileName){

  breakFun <- function(x){
    #function to replace empty lines with newline. 
    if(nchar(x) == 0){
      return("\n\n") #double newline to give same space as in the .md-file
    } else {
      return(x)
    }
  }

  storeLines <- readLines(fileName)

  cat(paste0(lapply(storeLines, FUN=function(x) breakFun(x)), collapse=""))

}
```

Output in .Rmd using chunk options `results = 'asis'`. Have tested with images (i.e. `![](http://example.com/logo.png)`) and normal HTML code. Should work for  most cases. See example bellow.

**about.md**

```
<!-- #### README -->

<!-- A brief description of the document. -->

#### README


A brief description of the document.

This is some more about text

##### This logo is important for the project

![optional caption text](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray-125.png)

Works with **bold** and *italics*

###### Another Header

<span style="color:blue">text is blue</span>
```

**.Rmd-file**

````
---
title: "Example"
runtime: shiny
vertical_layout: fill
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

pasteReadme <- function(fileName){

  breakFun <- function(x){
    #function to replace empty lines with newline. 
    if(nchar(x) == 0){
      return("\n\n") #double newline to give same space as in the .md-file
    } else {
      return(x)
    }
  }

  storeLines <- readLines(fileName)

  cat(paste0(lapply(storeLines, FUN=function(x) breakFun(x)), collapse=""))

}

```


Explore
======================================================================

### PLOT 1
```{r}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=cyl)) + geom_point()
```

### PLOT 2
```{r}
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=qsec)) + geom_point()
```

About
============================================================================


```{r, results='asis'}
pasteReadme("about.md")
```
````